# Web scraping both html text and image link with Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and tying to scrape the table from this URL using BeautifulSoup: http://www.espn.com/college-sports/basketball/recruiting/databaseresults?firstname=&lastname=&class=2007&starsfilter=GT&stars=0&ratingfilter=GT&rating=&positionrank=&sportid=4294967265&collegeid=&conference=&visitmonth=&visityear=&statuscommit=Commitments&statusuncommit=Uncommited&honor=&region=&state=&height=&weight=

So far, I've figured out how to pull the table data for each player's row, as well as the link to the school logo in each row. However, I'm having trouble combining the two. I want to pull the table data for each player (`player_data` in the code below) as well as their corresponding school logo image link (`logo_links`), and do so into one row per player in a saved CSV.

Below is what I have so far. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#! python3
# downloadRecruits.py - Downloads espn college basketball recruiting database info

import requests, os, bs4, csv
import pandas as pd

# Starting url (class of 2007)
url = 'http://www.espn.com/college-sports/basketball/recruiting/databaseresults?firstname=&lastname=&class=2007&starsfilter=GT&stars=0&ratingfilter=GT&rating=&positionrank=&sportid=4294967265&collegeid=&conference=&visitmonth=&visityear=&statuscommit=Commitments&statusuncommit=Uncommited&honor=&region=&state=&height=&weight='


# Download the page
print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

# Creating bs object
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

# Get the data
data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
type(data_rows)

player_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(data_rows))]

logo_links = [a['href'] for div in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "school-logo"}) for a in div.find_all('a')]


# Saving only player_data
with open('recruits2.csv', 'w') as f_output:
   csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
   csv_output.writerows(player_data)
```

Comment: Is `list(zip(player_data, logo_links))` what you want here?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar That nicely lines up the two lists, but I would like the `logo_links` to be part of the same list of `player_data`. When I export to CSV after zipping the lists as you suggested, all of `player_data` is in one column, and then `logo_links` is in a second column: https://d1ax1i5f2y3x71.cloudfront.net/items/2817413i333G1A3k1N44/Image%202017-08-12%20at%203.18.15%20PM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2746470. My ideal output is a CSV with one column matching each of the existing table's columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this.
Reason 1: You don't have to look up two times in the HTML for your content.
Reason 2: Following reason 1, you don't have to run the loops again.

```
player_data = []
for tr in data_rows:
    tdata = []
    for td in tr:
        tdata.append(td.getText())

        if td.div and td.div['class'][0] == 'school-logo':
            tdata.append(td.div.a['href'])

    player_data.append(tdata)
```

Small explanation -
Mainly, I haven't used list comprehension because of the `if` block which looks for the `div` block in `HTML` which has the required class name, if it does, it appends to the list of data it collects in `tr` tag.

Answer (score 2):

To append the `logo_links` elements to each list inside `player_data` you can do something like this:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> for p in player_data:
    p.append(logo_links[i])
    i+=1
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you. As I'm learning, any chance you could explain why this works? Mainly, what is `p` here?

Comment: I'm glad to help! In Python you can do a `for` loop to iterate over the elements of any *iterable*, such as a lists or strings. The first item in the sequence(in this case `player_data`) is then assigned to your variable (in this case `p`), and each time it loops it'll assign to the next value. Try writing `print(p)` inside the loop, you'll see better how it goes. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm) is a good reference on this.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks very much.